# Can a polynomial of degree $4$ have no turning points or no inflection points?

Tags: polynomials, quartics

Can a polynomial of degree $4$ have no turning points or no inflection points? If yes what is an example of polynomial of degree $4$ that show these feature. If no what is the minimum number of turning point or minimum number of points of inflection a degree $4$ polynomial can have.

Comment: The derivative of a quartic is a cubic, and any cubic has a real root by the intermediate value theorem, so a quadratic always has an extremum or an inflection point.

Comment: so what is the minimum number of inflection points a quartic can have?

Comment: It can have none: consider $ f(x) = x^4 $. (But it has an extremum.)

Comment: Graphing helps. For an M or W shaped graph there are 2 inflection points. Unless a trivial case of zero fourth degree coefficient  a single point of inflection is not possible.

Answer (score 2):

A degree-4 polynomial is of the form $f(x)=ax^4+bx^3+cx^2+dx+e$ where $a\ne0$. Differentiating gives $f'(x)=4ax^3+3bx^2+2cx+d$. If $f(x)$ has no critical points, then $f'(x)$ must not be $0$ for any real $x$. Since $f'(x)$ is a cubic polynomial, this is not possible. Thus a quartic always has at least one critical point.

In general, a quartic polynomial must have at least one turning point (as do all polynomials of even degree) though it can have no point of inflection (e.g. the polynomial $f(x)=x^4$).